# Determine an area of ​the bounded region under the curve

Tags: calculus, integration

We need to determine an area of ​​the bounded region under the curve
$x=\cos(\pi y)$ with $x=3;y=0;y=4$

So we can transcribe this as:

$$\int_{0}^{4}\cos(\pi y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Applying integration by substitution:

$$\int_{0}^{4\pi}\cos(u)\frac{1}{\pi}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{\pi}[\sin(u)]_{0}^{4\pi}=0.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: that's all, the x won't influence anything?

Comment: Wait. I’m posting something as an answer. Please reply.

Comment: Sketch the wavy sine curve. No need to integrate. Recognize an equivalent rectangle $3 \times 4$area by symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

<s>THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. THIS IS RATHER A QUERY TO CLARIFY THE OP’s INTENTION.</s> (Math SE doesn’t allow me to add pics in comments)

[image]

You want the red area (under y=4) or the blue area? Note that some parts overlap between the two.

EDIT: The red area is $$\int_0^4 (3-\cos \pi y)dy= 12-\int_0^4\cos(\pi y)dy = 12-\frac{\sin\pi y}{\pi} \bigg\vert _0^4=12.$$

 If you take signed areas, then your calculation is correct, otherwise the magnitude of the blue area is $$\int_0^4|\cos \pi y|dy=\int_0^{4\pi}\frac{|\cos u|}{\pi} du = \frac{8}{\pi}.$$

**P.S.** You may want to remember that the area of a “hill” of the curve of sin x or cos x between two consecutive zeroes is 2.

Comment: The question just asks to calculate the area of ​​the function and gives the mentioned values ​​of x and y. But I think it's asking to calculate the red area.

Comment: Ok I’ll edit to add the answer

Comment: Could you also show how to find the blue area?

Comment: You’ve done the blue area correctly. If you consider signed areas, that is.

Comment: Can you explain to me why we should calculate the dark blue area again? (to which the result was  $8/\pi$)

Comment: The dark blue area is just the overlap between the light blue and the red areas. Imo if they wanted the blue area they woul have asked the area bounded by x=cos $\pi$y, x axis and y=0, y=4.